# Trouble Populating NSMutableArray in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create an algorithm that essentially finds anagrams for a given word (Code below). After the user inputs their word, they press a button, and what it should be doing is looking at an array of words (populated from a txt file; I know that part works), and for each word taking the first letter and seeing if it is in the user's words, which I used a caseInsensitiveCompare to do. If all of the letters in the initial word are found in the user's typed word, it should add the word to an NSMutableArray. However, when I try to run it, testing by asking for the first word in the mutable array, I get the following error:

2014-08-07 13:56:52.231 HelloNoun[14796:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

This to me means that no words are being added to the mutable array. I don't understand this, since the user word itself should at least appear with the current code. I've looked through the documentation for everything I can think might be going wrong, and tried to Google an answer, but I'm still stumped as to why this isn't working.

I'm very green to coding, so any help with this issue or tips about things I should be doing differently (including about this post) are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)setOutput:(id)sender {
    NSString *lettersAvailableImmutable = self.userInput.text;
    NSMutableString *lettersAvailable;
    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    lettersAvailable = lettersAvailableImmutable];

    for (NSString *string in words)
    {
       int len = string.length;
        int runningTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            NSString *currentChar = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (i, 1)];
            int lettersAvailableLength = lettersAvailable.length;
            for (int j = 0; j < lettersAvailableLength; j++){
                NSString *currentInputChar = [lettersAvailable substringWithRange:NSMakeRange (j, 1)];
                if( [currentChar caseInsensitiveCompare:currentInputChar] == NSOrderedSame ) {
                    [lettersAvailable deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange (j, 1)];
                    runningTotal++;
                    lettersAvailableLength--;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (runningTotal == len){
             [matches addObject:string];
        }
    }

    self.userOutput.text = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is giving the error. None of the code you posted makes any attempt to access an array element.

Comment: Between the last two closing brackets, I used this to test:     self.userOutput.text = [matches objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Please update your question to actually include the code. Why would you not post the problematic code to start with?

Comment: OK, your code will crash any time there are no matches. Don't assume there are any matches.

Comment: The reason I didn't include the test code initially is that it works when I comment out the second and third for loops and populate matches simply with [matches addObject:string], it works, so I concluded that the problem must be in the latter for loops. And if I type in a word I know is in the words array, why would this algorithm not at minimum add itself to matches?

Comment: You need to debug the code to find out why it doesn't do what you think it should do. Learning to use the debugger is a crucial skill.

Comment: declare the mutable array without providing capacity like NSMutableArray * matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];,and then try it once..

Comment: @raki, I tried that, but got the same error.

Comment: @raki That would not cause any change in behavior at all.

Answer (score 3):

If `runningTotal` is never `==` to `len`, then no objects will be added to `matches`.

Calling `objectAtIndex:` with an index of 0 on an empty array will yield that exception.

The `initWithCapacity:1` does not create an array with one empty slot;  it merely advises Foundation that the array should be optimized to hold up to 1 elements.

Or, in short, `NSMutableArray` is not a sparse array.  There are no holes.

---

If no matches is expected, test for `array.length > 0` before accessing an object.

If no matches is unexpected, then debug your code.  Even `NSLog()` based debugging will work fine here.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours, I figured out the main problem (and learned more about debugging in the process) - I needed to copy the code creating lettersAvailable into the top for loop so that it would start anew each word. Now it works like a charm!